# WPF Gui refresh from different Thread

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a popup Gui with command binding,

```
 <Grid x:Name="popup" Visibility="Hidden" DataContext="{Binding Path=PopupMsg}" >


                    <TextBlock x:Name="tbMessage" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="20,70,10,0"
                           Text="{Binding Path=Message}" FontSize="16"/>

                    <Button x:Name="btnPopupOk" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding Path=OkContent}" Margin="10,40,10,10"
                        Command="{Binding}" CommandParameter="true" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
```

in the C# file i bind the command:

```
   CommandBinding okCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(OkCommand);
   okCommandBinding.Executed += popupButtons_Executed;
    okCommandBinding.CanExecute += okCommandBinding_CanExecute;
    CommandBindings.Add(okCommandBinding);
    btnPopupOk.Command = OkCommand;
```

Its working fine when I use it from the same Thread, when I get a callback from Web Service which is in a different thread I use Dispatcher to show a message, i can see the new text in the popup but the binding isn't working the button  remaining unavailable (CanExecute = false), When I click on the screen with the mouse, the popup update the real value of CanExecute and the button is appear available.

```
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
          new Action(
            delegate()
            {
                popup.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                popup.Focus();

            }));
```

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: Why do you need to change the CommandBinding of the button ?

Comment: @dmitri I think that he wish to know why the commands are being updated only after he clicked on the screen.

Answer (score 12):

this is the code snippet I use to fix any cross thread calls when updating a WPF UI.

```
 this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            (Action)delegate()
        {
            //Update code goes in here
        });
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Your issue isn't with threading, it's with what will cause a command to call `CanExecute`.

Usually only certain gui events will cause routed commands to update, and since WPF doesn't know to call `CanExecute` when data changes, it doesn't.

To manually cause all routed commands to update, call [CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.invalidaterequerysuggested.aspx). If the command is based on the message I'd call it when the message is changed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a dispatcher to get the visibility update to go through the main GUI thread (like you need to use Invoke with WinForms)

See [MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/360540eb-d756-4434-86f9-a3449f05eb55) for details.

Basically something like;

```
   popup.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, delegate() { popup.Visibilty = Visibility.Visible; popup.Focus(); });
```

Comment: It's hard to tell by the question, but I think he is already doing it, based on the last code section.